# I can't install kivy on python

Tags: python, kivy

I want to install kivy to python. To do this I type this command:

```
pip install -I Cython==0.21.2
```

It worked. But, when I type this command:

```
pip install kivy
```

I get this error:

```
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewGenerateMipmap
 referenced in function _glew_dynamic_binding
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewGetFramebuffer
AttachmentParameteriv referenced in function _glew_dynamic_binding
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewFramebufferRen
derbuffer referenced in function _glew_dynamic_binding
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewFramebufferTex
ture3D referenced in function _glew_dynamic_binding
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewFramebufferTex
ture2D referenced in function _glew_dynamic_binding
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewFramebufferTex
ture1D referenced in function _glew_dynamic_binding
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewCheckFramebuff
erStatus referenced in function _glew_dynamic_binding
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewDeleteFramebuf
fers referenced in function _glew_dynamic_binding
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewBindFramebuffe
r referenced in function _glew_dynamic_binding
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewIsFramebuffer
referenced in function _glew_dynamic_binding
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewGetRenderbuffe
rParameteriv referenced in function _glew_dynamic_binding
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewRenderbufferSt
orage referenced in function _glew_dynamic_binding
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewGenRenderbuffe
rs referenced in function _glew_dynamic_binding
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewDeleteRenderbu
ffers referenced in function _glew_dynamic_binding
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewBindRenderbuff
er referenced in function _glew_dynamic_binding
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewIsRenderbuffer
 referenced in function _glew_dynamic_binding
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewGenFramebuffer
s referenced in function _glew_dynamic_binding
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewActiveTexture
referenced in function ___pyx_pf_4kivy_8graphics_6opengl_glActiveTexture
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewAttachShader r
eferenced in function ___pyx_pf_4kivy_8graphics_6opengl_2glAttachShader
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewBindBuffer ref
erenced in function ___pyx_pf_4kivy_8graphics_6opengl_6glBindBuffer
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewBlendColor ref
erenced in function ___pyx_pf_4kivy_8graphics_6opengl_14glBlendColor
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewBlendEquation
referenced in function ___pyx_pf_4kivy_8graphics_6opengl_16glBlendEquation
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewBlendEquationS
eparate referenced in function ___pyx_pf_4kivy_8graphics_6opengl_18glBlendEquati
onSeparate
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewBlendFuncSepar
ate referenced in function ___pyx_pf_4kivy_8graphics_6opengl_22glBlendFuncSepara
te
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewCompileShader
referenced in function ___pyx_pf_4kivy_8graphics_6opengl_38glCompileShader
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewDeleteProgram
referenced in function ___pyx_pf_4kivy_8graphics_6opengl_58glDeleteProgram
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewDeleteShader r
eferenced in function ___pyx_pf_4kivy_8graphics_6opengl_62glDeleteShader
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewDetachShader r
eferenced in function ___pyx_pf_4kivy_8graphics_6opengl_70glDetachShader
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewDisableVertexA
ttribArray referenced in function ___pyx_pf_4kivy_8graphics_6opengl_74glDisableV
ertexAttribArray
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewEnableVertexAt
tribArray referenced in function ___pyx_pf_4kivy_8graphics_6opengl_82glEnableVer
texAttribArray
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewLinkProgram re
ferenced in function ___pyx_pf_4kivy_8graphics_6opengl_174glLinkProgram
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewSampleCoverage
 referenced in function ___pyx_pf_4kivy_8graphics_6opengl_186glSampleCoverage
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewStencilFuncSep
arate referenced in function ___pyx_pf_4kivy_8graphics_6opengl_196glStencilFuncS
eparate
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewStencilMaskSep
arate referenced in function ___pyx_pf_4kivy_8graphics_6opengl_200glStencilMaskS
eparate
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewStencilOpSepar
ate referenced in function ___pyx_pf_4kivy_8graphics_6opengl_204glStencilOpSepar
ate
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewUniform1f refe
renced in function ___pyx_pf_4kivy_8graphics_6opengl_218glUniform1f
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewUniform1i refe
renced in function ___pyx_pf_4kivy_8graphics_6opengl_222glUniform1i
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewUniform2f refe
renced in function ___pyx_pf_4kivy_8graphics_6opengl_226glUniform2f
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewUniform2i refe
renced in function ___pyx_pf_4kivy_8graphics_6opengl_230glUniform2i
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewUniform3f refe
renced in function ___pyx_pf_4kivy_8graphics_6opengl_234glUniform3f
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewUniform3i refe
renced in function ___pyx_pf_4kivy_8graphics_6opengl_238glUniform3i
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewUniform4f refe
renced in function ___pyx_pf_4kivy_8graphics_6opengl_242glUniform4f
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewUniform4i refe
renced in function ___pyx_pf_4kivy_8graphics_6opengl_246glUniform4i
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewUseProgram ref
erenced in function ___pyx_pf_4kivy_8graphics_6opengl_256glUseProgram
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewValidateProgra
m referenced in function ___pyx_pf_4kivy_8graphics_6opengl_258glValidateProgram
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewVertexAttrib1f
 referenced in function ___pyx_pf_4kivy_8graphics_6opengl_260glVertexAttrib1f
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewVertexAttrib2f
 referenced in function ___pyx_pf_4kivy_8graphics_6opengl_264glVertexAttrib2f
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewVertexAttrib3f
 referenced in function ___pyx_pf_4kivy_8graphics_6opengl_268glVertexAttrib3f
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewVertexAttrib4f
 referenced in function ___pyx_pf_4kivy_8graphics_6opengl_272glVertexAttrib4f
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewCreateProgram
referenced in function ___pyx_pf_4kivy_8graphics_6opengl_48glCreateProgram
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewCreateShader r
eferenced in function ___pyx_pf_4kivy_8graphics_6opengl_50glCreateShader
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewGenBuffers ref
erenced in function ___pyx_pf_4kivy_8graphics_6opengl_94glGenBuffers
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewGetActiveAttri
b referenced in function ___pyx_pf_4kivy_8graphics_6opengl_104glGetActiveAttrib
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewGetActiveUnifo
rm referenced in function ___pyx_pf_4kivy_8graphics_6opengl_106glGetActiveUnifor
m
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewGetAttachedSha
ders referenced in function ___pyx_pf_4kivy_8graphics_6opengl_108glGetAttachedSh
aders
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewGetProgramiv r
eferenced in function ___pyx_pf_4kivy_8graphics_6opengl_124glGetProgramiv
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewGetProgramInfo
Log referenced in function ___pyx_pf_4kivy_8graphics_6opengl_126glGetProgramInfo
Log
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewGetShaderiv re
ferenced in function ___pyx_pf_4kivy_8graphics_6opengl_130glGetShaderiv
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewGetShaderInfoL
og referenced in function ___pyx_pf_4kivy_8graphics_6opengl_132glGetShaderInfoLo
g
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewGetShaderSourc
e referenced in function ___pyx_pf_4kivy_8graphics_6opengl_136glGetShaderSource
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewGetUniformfv r
eferenced in function ___pyx_pf_4kivy_8graphics_6opengl_144glGetUniformfv
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewGetUniformiv r
eferenced in function ___pyx_pf_4kivy_8graphics_6opengl_146glGetUniformiv
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewGetVertexAttri
bfv referenced in function ___pyx_pf_4kivy_8graphics_6opengl_150glGetVertexAttri
bfv
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewGetVertexAttri
biv referenced in function ___pyx_pf_4kivy_8graphics_6opengl_152glGetVertexAttri
biv
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewIsBuffer refer
enced in function ___pyx_pf_4kivy_8graphics_6opengl_158glIsBuffer
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewIsProgram refe
renced in function ___pyx_pf_4kivy_8graphics_6opengl_164glIsProgram
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewIsShader refer
enced in function ___pyx_pf_4kivy_8graphics_6opengl_168glIsShader
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewBindAttribLoca
tion referenced in function ___pyx_pf_4kivy_8graphics_6opengl_4glBindAttribLocat
ion
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewBufferData ref
erenced in function ___pyx_pf_4kivy_8graphics_6opengl_24glBufferData
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewBufferSubData
referenced in function ___pyx_pf_4kivy_8graphics_6opengl_26glBufferSubData
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewCompressedTexI
mage2D referenced in function ___pyx_pf_4kivy_8graphics_6opengl_40glCompressedTe
xImage2D
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewCompressedTexS
ubImage2D referenced in function ___pyx_pf_4kivy_8graphics_6opengl_42glCompresse
dTexSubImage2D
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewDeleteBuffers
referenced in function ___pyx_pf_4kivy_8graphics_6opengl_54glDeleteBuffers
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewGetAttribLocat
ion referenced in function ___pyx_pf_4kivy_8graphics_6opengl_110glGetAttribLocat
ion
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewGetBufferParam
eteriv referenced in function ___pyx_pf_4kivy_8graphics_6opengl_114glGetBufferPa
rameteriv
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewGetUniformLoca
tion referenced in function ___pyx_pf_4kivy_8graphics_6opengl_148glGetUniformLoc
ation
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewShaderSource r
eferenced in function ___pyx_pf_4kivy_8graphics_6opengl_192glShaderSource
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewUniformMatrix4
fv referenced in function ___pyx_pf_4kivy_8graphics_6opengl_254glUniformMatrix4f
v
    opengl.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___glewVertexAttribPo
inter referenced in function ___pyx_pf_4kivy_8graphics_6opengl_276glVertexAttrib
Pointer
    build\lib.win32-2.7\kivy\graphics\opengl.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 79 unres
olved externals
     error: command '"C:\Users\ESES\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visu
al C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\link.exe"' failed with exit status 1120

    ----------------------------------------
Command "C:\Python27\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\us
ers\\eses\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-1jegbu\\kivy\\setup.py';exec(compile(
getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__
, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\eses\appdata\local\temp\pip-zzv3ab-record\
install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with er
ror code 1 in c:\users\eses\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-1jegbu\kivy
```

I have pygame module.
And, all of the installation with pip command, I get this error:

```
error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'

 ----------------------------------------
 Failed building wheel for kivy [or module_name]*
```

How can I solve them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install a prebuilt binary from the gohlke pythonlibs, just choose the appropriate version from  [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#kivy).